# choose the best one, second one,and third

Tags: r

there are two columns in a data frame, rank,pet, in the rank column, the most highest rank is "1", the second one is"2", the third one is "10".How do I create a new column b to choose the highest rank within three kinds of pets.For example, in the dog row, I would like to choose first row dog, in the cat row, I would like to choose sixth row cat.

```
rank<-c(1,2,7,3,10,2,10,2,1)
pet <-c("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","cat","bird","bird","bird")
a <-data.frame(rank,pet)
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Choose _The best one_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can do

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% group_by(pet) %>% top_n(1, -rank)
```

The `top_n` function allows you to return the extreme values for some column. We group by `pet` to get a different min for each pet.

Or if you wanted a new column, you could do

```
a %>% group_by(pet) %>% mutate(b=rank(rank)==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a$id <- 1:length(a$pet)
a <- a[order(a$rank),]
a <- a[order(a$pet),]
b <- a[!(duplicated(a$pet)),]
```

I add an ID column because otherwise you won't know which pet is which in the final result, then sort by rank, then sort by pet, then remove the 'duplicated' pets, which are those below the top-ranked pet.

Note, you said you're looking for a column b as your output, but I'm not sure how that would work, so I gave a data frame instead. If you just wanted a column of the ids, you could use this to only select the id column:

```
b <- a[!(duplicated(a$pet)),"id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the data.table object for fast and simple data manipulation:

```
library(data.table)
rankk<-c(1,2,7,3,10,2,10,2,1)
pet <-c("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","cat","bird","bird","bird")
a <-data.table(rankk,pet)
a[, b := min(rankk), by = pet]
```

I redefined "rank" as "rankk" because `rank` is a function name in data table.